# Need C# winform Coding for storing &retrieving multiple files (excel,pdf,docx) in network shared folder with proper credentials by clicking Save?

Tags: c#

C# Coding for storing and retrieving multiple files such as(excel,pdf,docx) in network shared folder with proper credentials while clicking Save (Windows application)?

I have tried a code like below, but this does not help me.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);

// http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/LogonUser.html    
IntPtr token;
LogonUser("username", "domain", "password", LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT);

WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(token);

WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate();

try
{
    File.Copy(@"c:\temp\MyFile.txt", @"\\server\folder\Myfile.txt", true);
}
finally
{
    context.Undo();
}
```

I have a windows form into which the user enters the data and then they will attach multiple files with the entry and then they save the entry of data stored in database and attachment files in network folder drive. And also need to retrieve the same.

Comment: you forget to pass your `token` to `LogonUser` method

Comment: also, are you sure, that you need impersonation for this? I mean why don't you save this files with credentials of the user that uses you app right now?

Comment: its actually a windows desktop application used by multiple users and they storing data in server database and they want to store multiple files like attachment with the same entry. i am not really sure about how i suppose to do this @vasily.sib

Comment: `File.Copy(@"c:\my_file.xls", @"\\share_name\my_file.xls");` ?